# Why does my shark not get damaged when colliding with other sharks?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I also get errors on my output such as:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   AttackonSharkwithMovement_fla::MainTimeline/fl_AnimateHorizontally()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   AttackonSharkwithMovement_fla::MainTimeline/fl_AnimateHorizontally_2()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   AttackonSharkwithMovement_fla::MainTimeline/fl_EnterFrameHandler_2()[

Scene 1 - Main Menu

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.system.fscommand
import flash.events.MouseEvent

stop();

//Button Scripts
Play_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Game");
}

Instructions_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_10);
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_10(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(6);
}

function quit (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fscommand ("quit");
}
Quit_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,quit);
```

Scene 2 - Game

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
stop();

//Variables
var rightPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var sharkSpeed:Number = 10;
var score1:Number = 0;
var maxHP:int = 100;
var currentHP:int = maxHP;
var percentHP:Number = currentHP / maxHP;

//Health Script
function updateHealthBar():void
{
    percentHP = currentHP / maxHP;
    healthBar.barColor.scaleX = percentHP;
}

//Button Scripts
MainMenu_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main Menu");
}

Instructions_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(6, "Main Menu");
}

//Keyboard Movement
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
function keyDownHandler(KeyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (KeyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if (KeyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    else if (KeyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = true;
    }
    else if (KeyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = true;
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = false;
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = false;
    }
}
function gameLoop(loopEvent:Event):void
{
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        shark.x +=  sharkSpeed;
    }
    else if (leftPressed)
    {
        shark.x -=  sharkSpeed;
    }
    else if (downPressed)
    {
        shark.y +=  sharkSpeed;
    }
    else if (upPressed)
    {
        shark.y -=  sharkSpeed;
    }
}

//AI Movement
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_AnimateHorizontally);
function fl_AnimateHorizontally(event:Event)
{

    enemy1.x +=  2;
    enemy2.x +=  2;
    enemy3.x +=  2;
    enemy4.x +=  2;
    enemy5.x +=  2;
    enemy6.x +=  2;
    megaladon.x +=  2;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_AnimateHorizontally_2);
function fl_AnimateHorizontally_2(event:Event)
{
    fishes.x +=  1.5;
}

//Colission
function hitsTheObject(e:Event)
{
    if (shark.hitTestObject(enemy1))
    {
        trace("player collided with enemy");

        currentHP -=  50;
        if (currentHP <= 0)
        {
            currentHP = 0;
            trace("You died!");
            MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Game Over");
        }
        updateHealthBar();
    }
}

//Score Script
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);
function fl_EnterFrameHandler_2(event:Event):void
{
    gameScore.text = String(score1);
    score1 +=  1;
    trace("gameScore.text is : " + gameScore.text);
    trace("score1 is : " + score1);
}

//Timer Script
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,50);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
myTimer.start();

function onTimer(e: TimerEvent):void
{
    myText_txt.text = String(myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount);
}

function onComplete(e: TimerEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "You Survived");
}
```

Scene 3 - You Survived

```
stop();

//Button Scripts
MainMenu_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_4);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main Menu");
}

PlayAgain_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_12);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_12(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Game");
```

}Scene 4 - Game Over

```
stop();

//Button Scripts
MainMenu_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_9);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_9(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main Menu");
}

PlayAgain_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_11);
function fl_ClickToGoToScene_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Game");
}
```

Comment: The 1009 error indicates that one of the objects being targeted by your code is out of scope.  This could mean that the object....
 
- doesn't have an instance name (or the instance name is misspelled)
- does not exist in the frame where that code is trying to talk to it
- is one of two or more consecutive keyframes of the same objects with no name (or a different name) assigned in the preceding frame(s).

You need to make sure that all your objects are defined on the frame in which they're being referenced.

Comment: All the instance names etc are fine, but when I go from Scene 2 to Scene 3/4, it's missing all the sharks, fishes etc while flash is still searching for them. How do i stop a eventListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified in the comments, you need to remove the eventListener which you can achieve with:

`removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_AnimateHorizontally);`.

I would suggest implementing the following line whenever you bind to a frame event such as `Event.ENTER_FRAME`

```
this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, function(){
    try{
         removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_AnimateHorizontally);
    }catch(error){
         //error handling optional in this case.
    }
});
```

This will get called ONCE only right before the object is destroyed/removed from the stage i.e. when you call `MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Game");`

> Note: You can just put all of your 'global' events into the try area - you don't need this call every time you add an event.
>
> > Additionally, you don't need this whatsoever for movieclips as all of your events will get cleaned up automatically once they are removed from the stage via the garbage collector.

Comment: @GentianGashi  scene 2

Comment: @GentianGashi that's not limited to scene 2 - you need to use this every time you add an event to the stage where the callback function is limited to a single frame.

Comment: I've fixed all the errors, everything works perfectly except for the collision, even though the errors are fixed, when my shark collides with another shark, health is unaffected, why?

Comment: Don't worry everyone, I've managed to figure it out myself, thanks for helping.